# how to match a crude description to a guide dataset and extract ID's in sas

Tags: sas

i have an excel sheet with a few descriptions of electronics.. eg: moto g first gen xt8001 etc.

I have another data set (guide list) with the Product and product_ID i want to match the product from the crude description to the guide list and come up with a product id that most suits my description.

Any help appreciated. really really new to sas

EXAMPLE:

Guide list has

```
product_ID  Product Description                 make     model  year   variant
er345c      2012 xata xt 1 juicer handheld      xata     xt1    2012   handheld
gh454f      1991 corona 112 400W heater         corona   112    1991   heater
ty445g      1999 blizzard 200W trimmer          blizzard -      1999   trimmer
er367c      2014 xata xt 2 juicer handheld      xata     xt2    2014   handheld
```

and crude description

xata handheld juicer

and i want the output to be like :

```
description           match1     match2
xata handheld juicer  er367c     er345c
```

we need to take the crude description and match it to the guide. 
I have already cleaned the data as much as possible.

Comment: Could you work out an example?

Comment: Is your data formatted as above, with the HTML tags, or is that just how you posted it here?

Comment: I have data in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you can count on in the crude description you might be able to simplify the following:

1) first take each word in the crude description

2) then use the like function and see if it is in the guide list by row

3) keep track of the number of words in each row of the guide list that match

4) select matches on highest counts